# Multi-line padded text in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, shadow, text-formatting

I am trying to implement a rectangular shadow effect in WPF, something like this:
https://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/

The shadow should follow each line of text, but it should not have a space between the lines. Also, the shadow will have some transparency, and this rules out adding a separate background to inline Runs. I tried this, and where the shadows overlapped the opacity values formed a darker color.

I have investigated so far TextBox, TextBlock and RichTextBox. I tried changing Run.Background, or selecting the text and changing the selection foreground/background. With no success, none of these are doing exactly what I need.

Basically what (I think) I need is a text formatting feature, that would allow me to create a properly wrapped text from a string IN MEMORY, with separate Runs for each and every line. After this, I could find out the pixel length of each Run, add these Runs manually to a RichTextBox or to a TextBlock, with manually created rectangles behind them.
Unfortunately, when I add text to a TextBlock or a RichTextBox, wrapping is applied to the Run itself, instead of creating separate Runs for each wrapped line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not received any replies, so I am trying to answer my own question.
My major problem with TextBlock was that if I added a slightly transparent background color to the inline Run objects, they formed a darker color as the lines overlapped slightly. To overcome this issue, I changed the Run background to non-transparent, and this way the 100% opacity values would not result in visibly overlapping lines. Then I changed the opacity of the whole TextBlock to 80% - and I got the result I expected.

Here is a sample xaml:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="23" FontFamily="Arial" TextBlock.LineHeight="24.65" 
            TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal"  TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"  Opacity="0.8">
    <Run Background="#FFFF0000" Text="This text here" />
    <Run Background="#FFFF0000" Text="will be visible across" />
    <Run Background="#FFFF0000" Text="multiple lines" />
</TextBlock>
```

Please note that the LineHeight value is slightly higher than the FontSize value. This makes sure that there will be no visible gaps between the lines.